# what is the relationship between COUPDAYSNC and COUPNCD

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, `COUPNCD` returns the date of the next coupon and `COUPDAYSNC` returns the number of days until the next coupon.

However, `COUPNCD(settlement, maturity, freq, basis)` - settlement is not always equal to `COUPDAYSNC (settlement, maturity, freq, basis)`

Why is this?

Comment: Could you show an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: Are you results calculated using the same basis ?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this, but I haven't been able to reproduce the behaviour described in the question. Without seeing a specific example, my guess would be that it's a numerical precision issue, or that the two functions are being fed different inputs, but this is pure speculation.